# How can I use non static variable(object ref) in static method without creating object inside that static method in java?is there any way to do it?

Tags: java, static

I'm new to Java. I get this error when running the code below

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field universityObj

But not getting error while using

```
        University universityObj = new University();
```

The code:

```
    
        public class University {
            String name;
            int stuno;
              String university_name = "Michigan University";
            University  universityObj;
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                
                University universityObj = new University();
                universityObj.name="Robert";
                universityObj.stuno=12;
                System.out.println(universityObj.name);
                System.out.println(University.university_name);
                display();
            }
            public void nonStaticDisplay()
            {
                System.out.println(name);
              
                System.out.println(stuno);
                
            }
           public static void display()
           {
               universityObj = new University();
               System.out.println(universityObj.name);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step.

1. The `display()` method should be non-static because it belongs to and should be used on the specific instance of the University class. Static methods can be used without creating an instance of some class. But in the case of the `display()` method, it wouldn't makes sense to do that because you need to display the university name, which firstly should be created and assigned.
2. It's not a good idea to create the object instance `University universityObj` inside the class in your case. Better to leave it only in the main method.
3. The `university_name` name is not static, so you can't access it without the class instance (object) like you're doing right now. `University.university_name` should be changed to `universityObj.university_name`.

These steps will bring us to a such piece of code:

```java
public class University {
    String name;
    int stuno;
    String university_name = "Michigan University";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        University universityObj = new University();
        universityObj.name = "Robert";
        universityObj.stuno = 12;
        System.out.println(universityObj.name);
        System.out.println(universityObj.university_name);
        universityObj.display();
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(stuno);
    }
}
```

Other things, which you should consider:

4. Read about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).
5. Use code formatting in your IDE. [Example for IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_file).
6. Check the `toString()` method from the `Object` class. It's intended exactly for what you're trying to achieve with your `display()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* simply pass a reference to the instance you want to be displayed. Like,

```
public static void display(University universityObj)
{
    System.out.println(universityObj.name);
}
```